# Systematic way of 'zeroing out' some values of a function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry, summation

Given a quasi-periodic trigonometric function $f(x)$, is there a systematic way of 'zeroing out' all values where $f(x)\ne1$?

For example, consider the function

$$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac {1}{2n+1} \sin (n^\frac {1}{\pi}) \pi x$$

The function has period $m$, and becomes aperiodic as $m \rightarrow \infty$. This is the plot for $m=20$:

[image]

Ideally what I'd like to do (not just with this function, but in general) is is to add a modifier to any $f(x)$ of this general type to create a new function $g(x)$ that, in the limit, produces

$$ f(x)\begin{cases}
 =1 \rightarrow g(x)=1\\    
 \ne1 \rightarrow g(x)=0
\end{cases}$$

A wild long-shot, I suspect. But I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> We could use *[Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)* as in
>   \begin{align*}
> g(x)=f(x)[[f(x)=1]]
> \end{align*}

Comment: Hmmm. That _describes_ $g(x)$, in that it tells the reader to only look at instances of $f(x)=1$ and ignore other values. But it doesn't produce a single analytic function with those properties, which is what I was after. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward: I does not *ignore* other values but instead set them to $0$. But of course, this is in general no longer an *analytic* function. I will delete this answer soon ....

Comment: I do appreciate the input, and I'll certainly think about how I might use it. So, it's useful. But I'm really after a general analytic solution, if such a thing exists.

Comment: @RichardBurke-Ward: Ok, I see.